# How do I fill up the array with the first 10 prime numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

This is probably a really simple problem to solve but for for some reason I just can't think of the correct solution!

We have a function int isPrime(int n) which returns a 2 if n is prime, a -1 if n is not positive and a 0 if n isn't prime. (We don't have to write any code for this function, we just assume that the code is already written so all we have to do is call this function). Using this function, we have to write a code fragment that fills up an integer array of size 10 with the first ten prime numbers. NOTE: Treat 1 as a non-prime number.

I've attempted a solution below but I don't think it's right:
NOTE: We just have to write a code fragment!

```
int a[10];
int n, i, result;

result = isPrime(n);

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (result == 1) {
         a[i] = n;
      }
   }
```

I have a feeling that I will have to use two for loops, one to cycle through the numbers being checked with isPrime and another one to loop through the positions in the array as I have above. But I'm not sure how it would look if I had two for loops. Any help is appreciated! Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. It will repeatedly find the next prime until you have found 10 of them.
Note: Since you did not provide an implementation of `isPrime`, this code is not tested. It is only meant to give you an idea of what it should look like.

```
int a[10];
int n, i, result;

n = 2;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Keep bumping n until we find a prime.
    while (!(isPrime(n) == 2)) {
       n++;
    }

    // Record the prime we just found.
    a[i] = n;

    // Ensure that we do not just record the same prime n times.
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question, why does it say !(isPrime(n) == 2) in the condition for the while loop?? Or, what is the condition in the while loop saying?

Comment: You should just as easily write `isPrime != 2` there. The purpose of the while loop is, as mentioned in the comment, to keep incrementing `n` as long as `n` is not prime.

Comment: And, for a while loop, shouldn't the "n++" only appear at the end of the while loop? (There's one right at the beginning of the while loop and there's one at the end in the code fragment you put up)

Comment: @Karen, I added curly braces to make it clear that the `while` loop stops after the first statement.

Comment: You could simplify the code with `n = 1; ... while (isPrime(++n) != 2 ) {} // find next prime`

Answer (score 2):

Start by having zero primes. While you don't have 10 of them, see if the next number is prime; if it is, add it to the next spot in the array if it is (and now you have one more prime).

(This straightforwardly translates into code. You need one loop, but two different counters: number of found primes, and number you're testing next)

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of Amaden's algorithm:

```
int a[10];
for (int n = 1, nprimes = 0;;)
    if (isPrime(++n) == 2) {
        a[nprimes++] = n;
        if (nprimes == 10)
            break;
    }
```